# SQLite cross reference unique combinations

Tags: sqlite

I've got two tables already populated with data with the given schemas:

```
    CREATE TABLE objects
    (
        id BIGINT NOT NULL,
        latitude BIGINT NOT NULL,
        longitude BIGINT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
    CREATE TABLE tags
    (
        id BIGINT NOT NULL,
        tag_key VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        tag_value VARCHAR(500),
        PRIMARY KEY (id , tag_key)
    )
```

object.id and tags.id refer to the same object

I'd like to populate a third table with the unique combinations of tag_key and tag_value. For example:

```
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO objects (id) VALUES (0);
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tags (id, tag_key, tag_value) VALUES (0, 'a', 'x');
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO objects (id) VALUES (1);
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tags (id, tag_key, tag_value) VALUES (1, 'a', 'y');
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO objects (id) VALUES (2);
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tags (id, tag_key, tag_value) VALUES (2, 'a', 'x');
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tags (id, tag_key, tag_value) VALUES (2, 'a', 'y');
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO objects (id) VALUES (3);
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tags (id, tag_key, tag_value) VALUES (3, 'a', 'x');
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO objects (id) VALUES (4);
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tags (id, tag_key, tag_value) VALUES (4, 'a', 'y');
```

Should result in 3 entries of

```
0: ([a,x]) 
1: ([a,y]) 
3: ([a,x][a,y])
```

Currently I have:

```
    CREATE TABLE tags_combinations
    (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        tag_key VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        tag_value VARCHAR(500)
    );
```

The id shouldn't be related to the original id of the object, just something to group unique combinations.

This is the query I have so far:

```
    SELECT
        t1.tag_key, t1.tag_value
    FROM
        tags t1
    WHERE
        t1.id
    IN
        (
    /* select ids who's every tags entry is not under one id in tags_combinations */
            SELECT 
                t2.id 
            FROM
                tags t2
            WHERE
                t2.tag_key, t2.tag_value
            NOT IN
            (

            )
        );
```

The part with the comment is what I am not sure about, how would I select every id from tags that does not have all of the corresponding tag_key and tag_value entries already under one id in tags_combinations?

To clarify exactly the result I am after: From the sample data given, it should return 4 rows with:

```
row id tag_key tag_value    
 0   0   a         x
 1   1   a         y
 2   2   a         x
 3   2   a         y
```

Comment: The table `objects` seems completely superfluous.  And you are gioing to drop table `tags` after populating `tags_combinations`? Or will you remove `tag_key` and `tag_value` from `tags` and replace them with `id_tags_combinations`? You should do either of the two in order not to introduce redundance in your data model.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten Kettner, objects actually has more information but I omitted it for this example. Ideally yes, I would replace the tags table with a id referencing the appropriate entry in tags_combinations.

Comment: BTW: So far there is only ID as a primary key in `tags_combinations`. Thus you cannot insert two records for ID 2. You are missing an additional GROUP_NUMBER column or whatever you want to call it, to store the grouping ID. (And ID being the primary key would be automatically filled with some value on insert.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is a set-based language. If you reformulate your question in the language of set theory, you can directly translate it into SQL:

- You want all rows of the `tags` table, except those from duplicate objects.
- Objects are duplicates if they have exactly the same key/value combinations. However, we still want to return *one* of those objects, so we define duplicates only as those objects where no other duplicate object with a smaller ID exists.
- Two objects A and B have exactly the same key/value combinations if

  - all key/value combinations in A also exist in B, and
  - all key/value combinations in B also exist in A.
- All key/value combinations in A also exist in B if there is no key/value combination in A that does not exist in B (note: double negation).

```
SELECT id, tag_key, tag_value
FROM tags
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tags AS dup
                  WHERE dup.id < tags.id
                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                    FROM tags AS A
                                    WHERE A.id = tags.id
                                      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                                      FROM tags AS B
                                                      WHERE B.id = dup.id
                                                        AND B.tag_key   = A.tag_key
                                                        AND B.tag_value = A.tag_value)
                                   )
                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                    FROM tags AS B
                                    WHERE B.id = dup.id
                                      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                                      FROM tags AS A
                                                      WHERE A.id = tags.id
                                                        AND A.tag_key   = B.tag_key
                                                        AND A.tag_value = B.tag_value)
                                   )
                 )
ORDER BY id, tag_key;
```

Comment: With some pre-filtering of data into a temporary table and then applying your query I reached my goal. Much appreciated, especially the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy in SQLite. We want to identify groups of tag key/value pairs. So we could group by id and get a string of the associated pairs with `group_concat`. This would be the way to do it in another DBMS. SQLite, however, cannot order in group_concat, so we might end up with `2: 'a/x,a/y'` and `5: 'a/y,a/x'`. Two different strings for the same pairs.

**Your best bet may be to write a program and find the distinct pairs iteratively.**

In SQLite you may want to try this:

```
insert into tags_combinations (id, tag_key, tag_value)
  select id, tag_key, tag_value
  from tags
  where id in
  (
    select min(id)
    from
    (
      select id, group_concat(tag_key || '/' || tag_value) as tag_pairs
      from
      (
        select id, tag_key, tag_value
        from tags
        order by id, tag_key, tag_value
      ) ordered_data
      group by id
    ) aggregated_data
    group by tag_pairs
  );
```

Ordering the data before applying group_concat is *likely* to get the tag pairs ordered, but in no way *guaranteed!* If this is something you want to do only once, it may be worth a try, though.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much for the advice. I'll solve this in the host language which is rather trivial. I was hoping to find a solution in SQLite to keep it as scalable as possible. Thanks again!

Comment: SQLite actually [guarantees](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening) that the inner ORDER BY is not optimized away (rule 16).

Comment: @CL.: And even so GROUP_CONCAT is far from being guaranteed to use that order in any way: `The order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary.` https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html .

Answer (score 0):

To merge multiple rows into one value, you need a function like [group_concat()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat).

The ORDER BY is needed to ensure a consistent order of the rows within a group:

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_concat(tag_key) AS tag_keys,
                group_concat(tag_value) AS tag_values
FROM (SELECT id,
             tag_key,
             tag_value
      FROM tags
      ORDER BY id,
               tag_key,
               tag_value)
GROUP BY id;
```

If you want to have keys and values interleaved, as shown in the question, you need to do more string concatenation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_concat(tag_key || ',' || tag_value, ';') AS keys_and_values
FROM (...
```

Comment: That's not quite what I'm after either. From the sample data given it should return 4 rows: 0: ([a,x]) 1: ([a,y]) 2: ([a,x]) 2: ([a,y])